# What is the "Genuine" and "Program" process in windows 10 startup?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

I went to check what if I had anything fishy in the startup of windows 10 and I saw this:

[image: Startup]

I disabled them since I don't know what they are, is it anyhting I should be worried about?

Comment: That’s not a lot of info to go off of. Maybe use SysInternals Autoruns tool to get more info? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Agreed. With this little information, we can't do much.

Comment: It’s something you have started.  Can you tell us which executable is being ran?  Use Autoruns to determine that information

Comment: Most people using Windows 10 would use the Startup Tab of Task Manager to see your screen shot. Nothing called "genuine" in any of my machines. Do a full scan with Windows Defender.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I found myself in the same position and I think I have found the reason of **Genuine**.
Do you have any Autodesk program installed on that machine? I think that may be the reason for you as well.
It should be a service checking the authenticity of your product.

A link from autodesk forums mentioning the service:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/genuine-service-how-to-uninstall-it-i-moved-to-a-different/td-p/9614666

Comment: É isto mesmo, obrigado!